# jQuery Mobile Slider Creates a new slider and my jquery object disappears?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, slider, uislider

So in my code I create a div as follows, `<div id='scrubber'></div>`, and later I do the following:

```
    $('#scrubber').html('<input type="range" name="prog" id="prog" value="0" min="0" max="'+event.jPlayer.status.duration+'"  />');
    $('#scrubber').slider();
```

This in turn produces 2 sliders. 1 of which is a standard html slider and the other is a jquerymobile slider. I had a simple work around, which was `$('#scrubber').hide();`, and that hid the plane jane html slider. However, at a different point in the code I need to update the value without user input:

```
$('#scrubber').val(event.jPlayer.status.currentTime).slider('refresh');
```

That should work in the theory, however, it just modifies the value for the html slider and NOT the jquery mobile slider. I don't think `slider('refresh')` is doing anything at all. Am I missing something? Did something change?

Comment: by html slider I don't mean a text field. It was creating that as well, and I hid it via css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to create a [JQM slider](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/forms/slider/):

```
$('#scrubber').html('<input type="range" name="prog" id="prog" value="0" min="0" max="'+event.jPlayer.status.duration+'"/>').trigger("create");
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For some reason that sorta works now. I need to work out why the slider isn't being updated still, but at least the jquery object doesn't disappear. Also that removes the need for the $('#scrubber').slider(); line, which in turn removes the extra slider that I was hiding before.

Comment: I'll accept this one, but I'll start a new topic, with the new problem! Thanks!